How to print string between two character using Linux/bash command
I am trying to find a Linux command which could give me the text between [ and ]. I tried standard grep and sed but none helped for far.Say the text is in LOGS. like -
    Starting mongo client..
Connecting to truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com (99.84.66.9:443)
global-bundle.pem    100% |********************************|  183k  0:00:00 ETA
MongoDB shell version v4.0.6
connecting to: mongodb://XXXx.amazonaws.com:27017/?authSource=XXX&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("XXXXXXX") }
MongoDB server version: 5.0.0
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        Listing Existing set of collections
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[
    "10w",
    "11w",
    "Test1",
    "Test2",
    "QA_Testing",
    "QueuesTest",
    "TestPagination",
]

I wanted the text only this collection names inside []
Tried so far

echo "$LOGS" | grep -o "\[.*\]"
echo "$LOGS" | sed -n 's/.*\[\([^]]*\)\].*/\1/p'
echo "$LOGS" | grep -o '\[\K[^\]]+'
echo "$LOGS" | awk -F'[][]' '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i}'

None of them helped so far. They are not showing any error but not also any output. Can anyone please help with the correct command which can help me

What if brackets appear inside brackets? What if they don't come in pairs?

the 1st one (echo | grep) works for me; the 2nd and 4th almost work except the literal [ and ] are being stripped off (fairly easy to insure they're added back in); please update the question with the complete output for each of your 4 coding attempts

the 4th attempt is designed to parse out multiple sets of [] from the single line of input; can your input include multiple pairs of []? if 'yes' then please state that in the question (and preferably show an example input and expected output)

@EdMorton: Those commands didn't give any output. Sorry I missed to mention that

Show your desired output for that sample input in your question (no comment).

Your recent edit turned this into a very different question from the one you originally asked, with a better possible solution than the suggested regexps. You should put this question back as it was when you asked it and then ask a new question about parsing this very different input format (and add the exact expected output), otherwise everyone who tried to help you was just wasting their time.

burcu's answer is perfect. As I prefer using the if statement in awk , here is my answer:
awk '{
    if ($0 == "[") {
        in_bracket = 1
        next
    }else if ($0 == "]"){
        in_bracket = 0
    }
    if (in_bracket) {
        print $0
    }
}' a.txt


@RCode Could you mark burcu's answer as the accepted answer? I didn't realize I was supposed to edit burcu's answer instead of posting a new one. My answer is basically the same as burcu's. I wrote most of the code myself, except for the next statement that I copied from burcu's answer, though I know there should be something like "continue in a for loop". I consider this plagiarism and I'm ashamed. But when my answer is marked as "accepted", I can't delete it. So could you unaccept it? And @burcu, I'm sorry for my behavior.

Of course, burcu's answer is correct enough. There is no need to edit anymore. Though for users who are not familiar with awk's syntax, burcu's coding style is not as easy to read as mine. So I will keep my answer here for addition notes. But I still feel my answer is not worthy of being an accepted answer.

You can extract the strings between brackets and then arrange after you have them. For example;

Using awk:
echo "$logs" | awk -F'[][]' '{print $2}'

Using sed:
echo "$logs" | sed -n 's/.*\[\([^]]*\)\].*/\1/p'

Using grep -oP:
echo "$logs" | grep -oP '(?<=\[)[^]]*(?=\])'


They will only return "apple, pineapple, wood-apple". If it is a necessity, you can add/concatenate/append the brackets after you retrieve them.

Edit: Based on the changes of the poster's edit and comment, I added the new solution as follows.
Your input is $logs can be processed such as:

Using awk:

echo $logs | awk '/\[/{flag=1; next} /\]/{flag=0} flag {printf "%s", $0}'
/\[/{flag=1; next} this section sets a flag when [ is encountered. /\]/{flag=0} this section unsets the flag when ] is encountered. Final part prints lines while the flag is set, effectively concatenating the multiline input.

Using sed:

echo $logs | sed -n '/\[/,/\]/p' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g' | sed 's/.*\[\(.*\)\].*/\1/'
You have to use sed multiple times. First one finds the lines between the [ and ]. Second one joins all lines together, and the last one extracts the content between [ and ].

Using grep and tr:

echo $logs | grep -oP '(?<=\[)[\s\S]*(?=\])' | tr -d '\n'
grep section matches all characters between [ and ] (including newlines) and tr section removes newline characters to create a single line.

Thanks for your time . I think in my case they are not giving any output as there looks like new line characters in between to. I have update the description with more specific to my scenario. Can you please check once and help?

updated my answer based on your change of the question. hope it helps!

echo $logs will do different things depending on the version of echo, the contents of logs, the directory you execute it from, environment variable settings, etc. Always quote your variables, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. Also, tr -d '\n' turns it's input into output that is no longer a valid POSIX text "file" and so what any subsequent call to a text processing tool such as grep, sed, or awk, does with that is undefined behavior. It is almost never the best approach to doing anything.

One of the things that echo $logs WILL do is turn all white space, including newlines, into single blank chars so then piping that to your awk script using a flag variable can;t work.

$ echo "$logs" | grep -o '\[.*]'
[apple, pineapple, wood-apple]

$ echo "$logs" | sed -n 's/.*\(\[.*]\).*/\1/p'
[apple, pineapple, wood-apple]

$ echo "$logs" | awk -F'[][]' '{print "[" $2 "]"}'
[apple, pineapple, wood-apple]

$ echo "$logs" | awk 'match($0,/\[.*]/){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'
[apple, pineapple, wood-apple]

$ echo "$logs" | gawk 'match($0,/\[.*]/,a){print a[0]}'
[apple, pineapple, wood-apple]

$ echo "$logs" | gawk '{print gensub(/.*(\[.*]).*/, "\\1", 1)}'
[apple, pineapple, wood-apple]

$ [[ "$logs" =~ \[.*] ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
[apple, pineapple, wood-apple]

The grep command requires the non-POSIX -o extension as provided by GNU grep, the final 2 awk commands require GNU awk for the non-POSIX extensions of gensub() and the 3rd argument to match(). Everything else will work in any version of the tools but since you're on Linux you probably have GNU tools anyway.
The above will do what you asked for given a single pair of matched [...] on a line as shown in your question but do different things for unmatched, multiple, nested, and/or overlapping pairs of [...] on a line - if you can have any of those situations and can't solve that problem yourself then ask a new question about that showing how you'd want those cases handled.
I'm using logs instead of LOGS for the reasons described at Correct Bash and shell script variable capitalization.

Hi @Ed Morton, thanks for your detailed write up. Thanks for your time too. I think in my case they are not giving any output as there looks like new line characters in between to. I have update the description with more specific to my scenario. Can you please check once and help?

At least for your value of LOGS (you didn't specify the general format of the text), the following should work in bash:
LOGS='[apple, pineapple, wood-apple]'
echo ${LOGS//[][]/}

The // causes all occurances of the pattern to be removed. The pattern is a wildcard (i.e. glob) pattern, in this case a character class [ ... ], containing the two characters ][.
